# rails db:migrate rails aborted! Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

I'm running this migration:

```
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :admins do |t|

      t.string "first_name" :limit => 30
      t.string "last name", :limit => 30
      t.string "email", :default => '', :null => false
      t.string "password" ,:limit => 40
      t.timestamps

    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :admins
  end
end
```

I get an error saying:

> rails db:migrate rails aborted! Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Your error means that your rails app can't login to the mysql database because your credentials are defined wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, this is correct migration code:

```
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
    create_table :admins do |t|
      t.string :first_name, limit: 30
      t.string :last_name, limit: 30
      t.string :email, default: '', null: false
      t.string :password ,limit: 40

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :admins
  end
end
```

**or just change** [difference](https://rubyinrails.com/2014/05/14/rails-migration-change-vs-up-down-methods/)

```
class CreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :admins do |t|
      t.string :first_name, limit: 30
      t.string :last_name, limit: 30
      t.string :email, default: '', null: false
      t.string :password ,limit: 40

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

About error, your `database.yml` for development env, should looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: your_db_name
  username: your_user
  password: your_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

Comment: No need for both "change" and "down" methods. "change" is enough.

Comment: @sudo Yes and no. I've expanded answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your database.yml file, in the config-directory. The error is caused by mysql responding with an authentication error, for your root user. You might wanna check http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database for information on the database.yml syntax.

You can furthermore check and validate the login in shell by running `mysql -u root -p` and try entering your password.